# How to fix error 400 on the below VBA code

Tags: excel, vba

The below code is a test to copy data from one worksheet into another, I keep receiving error 400 and I am not sure what I am missing.

```
Sub test()
Dim TravelRequest As Workbook
Dim MainBook As Workbook
Set TravelRequest = ThisWorkbook
'Open All workbooks first:
Set MainBook = Workbooks.Open("FILELOCATIONREDACTED")


TravelRequest.Sheets("Sheet4").Range("C5").Copy

MainBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the macro code in sheet1 and it was working on sheet4 (I need to go to bed)